# compile .C file Include library using mex - error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol - for NPTrackingTools

Tags: c, matlab, visual-c++, 3d, mex

Hello I'm trying to build simple C function with external commands provide by library NPTrackingTools API

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include "mex.h"
 #include "NPTrackingTools.h"
 void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                 int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    int ret1,ret2,ret3;
    ret1=TT_Initialize();
    ret2=TT_FinalCleanup();
    ret3=TT_Shutdown();
    printf("Hello, World! \n");
    return 0;
}
```

I tried the following compiler code

```
mex -v '-Id:\or hirshfeld\onedrive\work control lab aero summer 2014 technio\C_code' '-LD:\or hirshfeld\onedrive\work control lab aero summer 2014 technion\C_code' '-lNPTrackingToolsx64.lib' test_C_compile_with_include_trackingtools.c
```

I have all files in the same directory "d:\or hirshfeld\onedrive\work control lab aero summer 2014 technio\C_code"

but the compiler return an error that he can't understand my commands

> Error using mex    Creating library
>   test_C_compile_with_include_trackingtools.lib and object
>   test_C_compile_with_include_trackingtools.exp
>   test_C_compile_with_include_trackingtools.obj : error LNK2019:
>   unresolved external symbol __imp_TT_Initialize referenced in function
>   mexFunction test_C_compile_with_include_trackingtools.obj : error
>   LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_TT_Shutdown referenced in
>   function mexFunction test_C_compile_with_include_trackingtools.obj :
>   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_TT_FinalCleanup
>   referenced in function mexFunction
>   test_C_compile_with_include_trackingtools.mexw64 : fatal error
>   LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals

I tried different variation but still have the same problem, can you help me?

Thanks

Or Hirshfeld

אור הירשפלד

Comment: all the blank spaces in your pathnames may be causing a problem; try surrounding the pathnames with "" ?

Comment: my git hub project: [link](https://github.com/orhirshfeld/Motive-S-function.git) 'https://github.com/orhirshfeld/Motive-S-function.git`

Comment: @TryHard thanks for the comment, i tried the following code and still the same problem. mex -v '-I"D:\or hirshfeld\onedrive\work control lab aero summer 2014 technion\C_code\Motive-S-function"' '-lNPTrackingTools' '-L"D:\or hirshfeld\onedrive\work control lab aero summer 2014 technion\C_code\Motive-S-function"' test_C_compile_with_include_trackingtools.c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library (.lib) you are trying to link to seems to be a C++ library, although these functions have C entry points (check with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)).  I got it to compile by renaming your `mexFunction` source from .c to .cpp, putting the header and source in the same folder, and compiling like:

```
mex -v  -L. -lNPTrackingToolsx64 test_C_compile_with_include_trackingtools.cpp
```

although you can simply list object files on the command line like this:

```
mex -v test_C_compile_with_include_trackingtools.cpp NPTrackingToolsx64.lib
```

Just list the source file first or the output .mexw64 file will have the name of the library!

Also note that you will need LIBIOMP5MD.DLL to run the code.  This is Intel's OpenMP runtime library and you can find it all over as it is freely redistributable.

Comment: Thank you so much, all i needed is rename it .CPP so it compiled in C++. I  didn't do anything extra to link it to Intel's OpenMP runtime library, I guess Matlab already link it by defualt.

Comment: @OrHirshfeld It's not linked by MATLAB, it's a runtime linked library (a DLL).  It just so happens that libiomp5md.dll is included with MATLAB for its own use and it's OK for your program to use it too.

Comment: Thank again, how should i include it? By compiling line using -l and -L?

Comment: @OrHirshfeld It's automatically loaded at runtime if it can be found on your path.

Comment: Your tips are very helpful, So i just need to copy the dll file to my project folder? Should i also copy some header files or Lib?

Comment: @OrHirshfeld To run it?  No headers, just the dlls.  Open the MEX file with Depencency walker to see.